# Titanium Ti.Android Undefined in ios

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am very new to Titanium Developer. I assigned an Titanium project for made UI changes to latest ios look and feel. When I run App I will always throwh exception like Ti.Android is undefined.

The **previous version of the SDK is 3.0.2** but I am now configured the **latest version 3.2.3GA**

Current the app run without any error in Android only show error as undefined for Ti.Android in Ios only.

My Dough whether Ti.Android is strict to Android platform only or its for both ios and android or else its is deprecated for ios in latest version.

Please help.

Comment: How can you find the android OS in iOS. Write it in a condition like `if(Titanium.Platform.name == 'android'){Ti.Android.......}`

Comment: But the the same source was built for ios, probably in older version 3.0.2. It's also available in app store.  My dought is whether   Titanium.Android is depricated in latest  version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in the docs `Ti.Android` is available only for Android (Ti > 1.5, see the logo on the right) http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Android however if you try to access only `Ti.Android` it should work and return `undefined` because `Ti` has no `Android` property. You shouldn't see any errors... ,but you are probably trying to access some other property for instance `Ti.Android.XXX` which obviously can't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the platform first before using any platform-specific modules/function. You could add a function on your commonjs to check it.

```
var osname = Ti.Platform.osname;    

function isAndroid() {
    return osname === 'android';
}

function isIOS() {
    return osname === 'iphone' || osname === 'ipad';
}

function isMobileWeb() {
    return osname === "mobileweb";
}
```

On your controller, you then do something like this:

```
var fn = require('commonjs');

if (fn.isAndroid()) {
    //the things you do for android only
} else if (fn.isIOS() {

} else if (fn.isMobileWeb()) {

}
```